# How to write mathematically $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For $i \in A_i = (i,i+1)$

Find $\mathbb{R} - ($ $\bigcup\limits_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} A_{i})$

This is obviously all $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Z}$ But is there a better way to say this symbolically?

Comment: Yes. Say only $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, each $A_i$ is an interval between two integers.  The union of all the $A_i$ is all the noninteger reals.  The difference is then $\Bbb Z$

Comment: Yes ofcourse, silly on my part. Thank you